# PHP ternary function with an IF and OR statement

Tags: php

Can I use a ternary function to replace this code?

```
if (isset($_POST['something']) || ($_POST['something']=="")){
    $a= "N/A";
else{
    $a= $_POST['something'];
}
```

I am trying this but it's not working...

```
$a = (isset($_POST['something']) || ($_POST['something']=="")) ? $_POST['something'] : 'N/A';
```

I am sending a form which a field can be empty and i want to replace for something like N/A or 'No aplica' for spanish when the user leave the field blank.

Comment: You want `$a = (isset($_POST['something']) || ($_POST['something']=="")) ? 'N/A' : $_POST['something'];`

Comment: @Spooky wont that always be 'N/A'?

Comment: I think the logic of this `if` is off. If it `isset` or it is empty you are setting it to `N/A`. Is that what you want, I don't think you will ever get to the actual value with that..

Comment: Yeah you guys are right, I was walking my dog and realize that I was checking for something weird because is always going to be set... but now I changed it to $a = $_POST['something']=="" ? $_POST['something'] : 'N/A'; and still receiving blank on the email... console log gives me a blank so I should receive N/A on the email...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
$a = (!empty($_POST['something'])) ? $_POST['something'] : 'N/A';
```